# Receiving a string of "chars" and try to count how many of them are there of the same kind by using pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, constants

I have this function that receives a string of "chars". I'm trying to go through that string and use pointers to see if the second element is the same as the first. SO  lets say I have aaabbccddd, i would want to write into an array that i have 3a, 2 bs, 2cs and 3ds. I'm really struggling in figuring out if the second string is the same as the first by using pointers. I created this temp pointer and i do temp++. THis essentially just shows everything after the second term and so on...How can i individually look at the second term and compare it to the first term with just pointers.

```
void RLE<T>::Compress(const T* input, int inSize)
{

   delete m_Data;
    m_Size = 0;

    T * m_Data;
    m_Data = new T[inSize*2];


    int runSize = MaxRunSize();

    const T * temp;
    temp = input;

    temp++;
```

This part right here always gives me errors and it says that I have a Bad pointer. I understand that this essentially doesn't work because my input pointer is longer than the temp pointer i created. and my array never gets initialized

```
    if  (temp == input)
    {
        std::cout<<"here"<<std::endl;
        int number = 1;
        number++;
        m_Data[0] = number;
        m_Size++;
        std::cout<<temp;
        m_Data[m_Size] = *temp;


    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Please give us the exact error

Comment: Are you trying to implement [RLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your error right at the start?

```
delete m_Data;
m_Size = 0;

T * m_Data;
```

This wouldn't work since `m_Data` is undefined at that point, unless, going by the naming, that is a member as well, in which case you should not redefine it.

Shouldnt you do

```
if(temp[i] == temp[i+1]) //or something like that
```

instead of

```
if  (temp == input)
```

Comment: m_Data is initialized earlier. it's part of a struct class. i'ts a member of the struct class

Comment: @user1665569 then you should remove the line `T* m_Data;`

Comment: that actually helped Karthik. if i do temp++ and try to compare it with the first char of input, it still doesn't recognize that they're the same

Comment: @user1665569 yes, without `[]` you are comparing addresses of the characters, not the values.

Comment: thank you so much for your help. i've been stuck in this problem for a while now